# Azure Function calls itself after 3 minutes

Tags: azure, azure-functions

i have the following code in my azure function with 5 minutes manual timeout.

[image: Function Code]

when i run the above function in azure, i see the function creates a new instance after 3 minutes.(check the below image)
[image: Logs from azure]
both the instances completes successfully ,but returns  **Status: 504 Gateway Timeout** which in turn fails my function execution.
i have hosted the function in **App Service Plan**, and also increased the timeout in **host.json** file to 10 minutes

```
"functionTimeout": "00:10:00"
```

Comment: How is the trigger defined?

Comment: i have used http trigger for the function.

Comment: @ABaig as mag_zbc suggests, please do not post bitmaps of code and function output. This makes it much harder to work with. e.g. no easy way to grab the invocation IDs without manually copying them.

Comment: Also, clarify how you are invoking the function, and what makes you believe that the function is calling itself.

Comment: Do not post code as images, ever. Please edit your question, remove the images and add the code as text. [Why may I not upload images of code on SO when asking a question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/1288408)

Comment: @David Ebbo i used the image instead of code as it was giving me syntax error for my code making it unable to save. thanks for the suggestion will keep it in my checklist henceforth.

Answer (score 0):

Several questions in here:

1. Timeouts - The function timeout in host.json applies to the underlying function runtime; not the http pipeline. You should not have an http function running longer than a minute. The http calls will timeout independently of the runtime (as you see with the 504). However, you could use that timeout for a long-running (ie, 60 minute on appservice plan) queue trigger. If you need a long-running function, the http call could queue a message for a queue trigger, or you could use the Durable Function support.
2. Why is it invoking again? The simplest interpretation here is that your function is just receiving a second http request message. Do you have evidence that's **not** the case? You could bind to the HttpRequestMessage and log additional http request properties to track this down.

Comment: should i use a different trigger for my function?can you suggest any(actually need to implement azure functions for my long running web-jobs. above function was a sample i was trying.) and about invoking again, i am testing the function in azure portal, hence it is invoked only once manually.